# Code Works in JSFiddle But not Localhost, Please help me find out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, lamp

I am having a problem here getting my code to run properly on my LAMP server localhost when I can get it to run on JSFiddle.. Now normally when this happens, it is something small that I kick myself later on about. However as you all know, More sets of eyes on a problem are better than one set. Please If anyone can, help me find the solution to my problem.

Here is the JS Function I am using on JSFiddle. This function takes a series of checkbox's and populates a sort list on the next JQuery Fade In Form. Here on JSFiddle its all displays At once, but on my actual doc its 2 forms (still both in index) that fade in and out when the user hits next.

https://jsfiddle.net/1ukyLgnh/5/

Here is my Repository that has my Full Index.html File,

https://github.com/dhierholzer/Basiconlineordering

Note:
The function in my index file is located at the bottom under the $('#btn4').click(function(e){  }

It may help to download my file from Github and run it if you have a web server running.

The fuction that I am using (That works in FSFiddle and not my Index.html file) is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();


    //Some code
    $("#sortable3").sortable();
    //Some more code
    $("#addStuff").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemSelector = $("#myList li"),
            items = [],
            dataObj = {};
        $.each(itemSelector, function(i, v) {
            items.push($(v).val());
        });
        //I Am Sure There Is A Better Way Of Sending Checked Items Than A Ton Of IF Statements, However This Works..
        if(document.getElementById('bacon').checked) {
            items.push($("#bacon").val());
        }        
        if(document.getElementById('bananapeppers').checked) {
            items.push($("#bananapeppers").val());
        }          
        if(document.getElementById('blackolives').checked) {
            items.push($("#blackolives").val());
        }        
        if(document.getElementById('greenpeppers').checked) {
            items.push($("#greenpeppers").val());
        }         

        dataObj.stuff = items;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sortable3").empty();
                $.each(data.stuff, function(k, v) {
                    $("#sortable3").append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
                })
            },
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false
        });
    });
});
```

Any Comments and help would be useful,

Thanks again!

Comment: Did you load jQuery? Is your jQuery version 2.0 and above? If so, is it running in IE?

Comment: Are there errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Are you using `/echo/json/` in the AJAX call on your local server? Do you have a script like that on your server?

Comment: Its fully working for me. I would recheck your console. It broke without using a webserver. I'm going to assume you are either not running a server or your just double clicking and opening the file instead of navigating to the server URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding - 
contentType : 'application/json'

to your ajax request object